# Unable to add repository key to local keychain

Tags: 14.04, bash, repository

I want to install Docker application on my Ubuntu, but i can't execute a command to add Docker repository key to my local keychain. Here's this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
```

**And here's output:**

```
imran@imran-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
[sudo] password for imran:
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.Qm3en119gf --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/dotcloud_ubuntu_lxc-docker.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/fossfreedom_ubuntu_packagefixes.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/oibaf-graphics-drivers.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/shutter-ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-wine_ubuntu_ppa.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xorg-edgers-ppa.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
gpg: requesting key A88D21E9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key A88D21E9: "Docker Release Tool (releasedocker) <docker@dotcloud.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output to your pastebin:

```
gpg: key A88D21E9: "Docker Release Tool (releasedocker) <docker@dotcloud.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Means: OK!  Great! Fantastic!  now please execute the next command.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 11 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: ok, i will accept this answer, but next command gives new errors, but this issue needs new thread, so yes, i will accept this.

Comment: Drop me a note @Fabby for the next question.  ;-)

Comment: A godsend – :-)